# Area of one raster cell

Tags: qgis-3, area

I need to identify the area (m2) of each cell in a raster layer. I do know how to find the cell size under metadata (which in my case is [0.00980834,-0.00748333]); but how do I convert this into m2 or km2?

Comment: A square degree on the Earth can vary from ~3600 square nautical miles at the Equator to ~31 square nautical miles near the North Pole. You can only convert degree pixels to ground units when you know where (and it differs for each step north and south)

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you. So, my problem is than: I have one raster layer with each cell size of [0.00980834,-0.00748333]. For each cell I have calculated an energy demand (kWh/ha). I would like to calculate the aggregated energy demand within polygons of this layer. I have considered to use zonal statistics, but that only gives me the mean value within each polygon - I want the exact aggregated value of the polygon area. In other words, I want to convert the unit from kWh/ha/cell to kWh/cell; but I don't know the area of the cells. Thoughts?

Comment: Too many variables to answer in comment. You have to choose vector or raster, calculate area by row, and build a float area raster.